# How to authenticate a specific client program?

Tags: authentication, certificates, client, challenge-response

I have a server application which provides functions to a client program. The client is also programmed by me. Now I want to authenticate the client program itself (not any user) before using my service. I want to achieve that my service can only be used by executing **my** client software. The problem is, that both server and client aren't necessarily connected to the internet. Therefore, any authentication via a third entity cannot be used.

In my opinion, some secret has to be compiled into the executable of the client program and something like a challenge-response-procedure has to be performed.

What do you think about this thought or do you any have other ideas?

I've already thought about a client certificate but the certificate itself has to be compiled into the executable, too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot ensure that the program talking to the server is **your** program. Anything client-side can be compromised, and any communication coming from the client can be altered.

The multiplayer game industry is facing a decades old battle against the kind of problem you stated, and even with millions in funding, expert programmers and a lot of money at stake, they cannot prevent people from using *custom client software* to interfere with their systems.

> some secret has to be compiled into the executable

And the attacker can extract this secret, reverse-engineer the challenge-response protocol, and write its own client.

> thought about a client certificate

It won't work. Attackers can extract the certificate and misuse it, like the secret.

You can obfuscate the code, add certificates, add secret data, checksums, and any client-side measure, they will not prevent a dedicated attacker from writing its own client if he has enough incentive.